# Why ng-model does not update controller value select?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-model

This is the code HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="SelectCtrl">
    <p>selected item is : {{selectedItem}}</p>
    <p> age of selected item is : {{selectedItem.age}} </p>
    <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.name for item in items">
    </select>
</div>
```

This is the code AngularJS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('SelectCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{name: 'one', age: 30 },{ name: 'two', age: 27 },{ name: 'three', age: 50 }];
    $scope.selectedItem = $scope.items[0];
    console.log($scope.selectedItem); //it's not update :(
});
```

in the view the new value updated every time I change the select, but the controller does not update the current value of the select. What should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: how do you know the controller doesn't have the new value? in the code you provided, you are only calling `console.log` once (on page load).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get updated or change value inside your controller, you could write `ng-change` function on it. Then you could check the updated value inside controller.

**Markup**

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.name for item in items"
  ng-change="changeSelectedItem()">
</select>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.changeSelectedItem = function(){
   console.log($scope.selectedItem);
}
```

Other way could be you could simply use `{{selectedItem}}` on html somewhere. That will also give an idea about how `selectedItem` value is updating.

Comment: @VirajNalawade You should go for it..Thanks for appreciation.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Because you are always taking the first item of the array in the controller,

```
$scope.selectedItem = $scope.items[0];
console.log($scope.selectedItem);
```

Just change your JS like this,

```
$scope.changeSelectedItem = function(){
   console.log($scope.selectedItem);
}
```

And the View use the ng-change to get the selected item

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.name for item in items"
  ng-change="changeSelectedItem()">
</select>
```